# Is there BSD jail or Linux container functionality in Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualization

I'd like to be able to work with a poorly-behaving application without using a VM (becuse it requires a whole extra license). Does Windows have something like BSD's jails or Linux's containers?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/161507/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-chroot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try [WinJail](http://www.winquota.com/wj/index.html):

> WinJail is full implementation of chroot, with additional features
>   like "copy-on-write" mechanism applied to chroot'ed files, additional
>   registry based chroot, and more.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something called a "[virtual sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29)" program like [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) or [Avast Pro version and Internet Security version](http://www.avast.com/) come with a sandboxing feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Remote Desktop Services" (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee236407 ) is what you are looking for but I think it exceeds your budget :)

Comment: Remote Desktop sessions are not sandboxed in any significant way.  There is support for mixing RD with virtualization, but the OP specifically doesn't want to virtualize.

Comment: well, "behaves poorly" is a lose requirement as well. a pseudo-virtualized container might as well require a "whole extra license" (for windows? for the software? for the software coz it runs on a terminal server?) because you might run multiple instances in parallel etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is [turbo.net](http://turbo.net). It allows to run applications in their own sandbox, preventing it from containing you're system with files, registry entries etc.

If you need if for a your application, you probably want to start with a 'clean' machine. Like

> turbo run --mount=C:\FolderWithUntrustyApp clean C:\FolderWithUntrustyApp\untrusty.exe

You also run the installer in it.

> turbo run --mount=C:\FolderWithUntrustyApp clean C:\FolderWithUntrustyApp\installer-untrusty.exe

Note: It's not designed to contain things like viruses and advanced malware, which exploit kernel bugs or